# In Hive shell executing query select * from emp getting all values as null

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

hive> `select * from emp;`

```
OK
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

the data in hdfs
1201  Gopal       45000    Technical manager
1202  Manisha     45000    Proof reader
1203  Masthanvali 40000    Technical writer
1204  Kiran       40000    Hr Admin
1205  Kranthi     30000    Op Admin
```

can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: your data in not properly loaded in Hive Table. Check the DDL statement for emp table..

Comment: Did you use External Table command ? to import the data ?

Comment: this one is the query i have used to create table:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( eid int, name String,
salary double, destination String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

Answer (score 0):

How did you define the table schema, I mean what was create table emp( .....
you can check with "describe extended emp"

To me it looks like either column data type or fields terminated by is mismatched.

Comment: here is the execution

Comment: hive> describe extended emp;
OK
eid                  int                                      
ename                string                                   
salary               double                                   
designation          string                                   
dept                 string               Department name

Comment: this looks ok..what about delimiter?? is that tab (\t)..remember input should be tab separated else it will read as single column and since your first column is int so there will be mismatch. You can  try it by making {1201,Gopal,45000 ,Technical manager} input comma separated and while creating table put as "fields terminated by ','"

Comment: this one is the query i have used to create table:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( eid int, name String,
salary double, destination String)
COMMENT ‘Employee details’
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

Comment: thank you very much it was delimiter problem. solved

Answer (score 0):

check the `delimiter`.
Create the table using `tab` delimiter.

Comment: thank you very much it was delimiter problem. solved

Comment: Mark it as answer if it helped you and issue was resolved